# Ionic Cordova Plugin AudioToggle Not Imported Correctly

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an Ionic app with the ApiRTC library for video chat functionality. However, the video audio comes out the headset speaker on phones, where I want it to come out the main speaker. The [ApiTRC Cordova FAQ](https://apirtc.com/faq/) suggests using the [AudioToggle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-audiotoggle) plugin, so that is what I am attempting to import into my project.

To import I did `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-audiotoggle --save` in the root of my project directory. Then I attempted to call the plugin in my code like this:

```
declare var AudioToggle;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams...) {
    AudioToggle.setAudioMode(AudioToggle.EarPiece);
}
```

However, it says AudioToggle is undefined and a function "setAudoMode" does not exist for "undefined."

Am I importing a Cordova plugin the wrong way, or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by declaring the plugin, and then only setting the audio mode when I started an audio event (video call in my case).

```
declare var AudioToggle;

startVideoCall(){
  AudioToggle.setAudioMode(AudioToggle.SPEAKER);

  //Do other code...
}
```